# Use AzureStor R library to interact with ADLSgen2 resource

Tags: r, azure, azure-blob-storage, rstudio, azure-data-lake

I would like to (i) list the contents of a specific directory that sits in a container of an ADLSgen2 storage account using RStudio, and (ii) read a csv that is stored in that directory as a DataFrame.

It is important to note that I only have READ access to the specific directory in question (via combination of Azure AD groups & ACLs)

```
library("AzureStor") 
library("readr")
library("AzureAuth")

tenant_id <- "hidden"
client_id <- "hidden"
client_secret <- "hidden"
storage_account <- "hidden"
container_name <- "hidden"
directory_path <- "hidden"
file_path <- "hidden"

auth <- AzureAuth::get_azure_token(
  resource = "https://storage.azure.com",
  tenant = tenant_id,
  app = client_id,
  password = client_secret
)

adls <- adls_endpoint(
  endpoint = sprintf("https://%s.dfs.core.windows.net", storage_account),
  token = auth
)

directory_contents <- list_storage_containers(adls, container_name, directory_path)
print(directory_contents) # I need access to the entire ADLS to run this

cont <- storage_container(adls, container_name)
list_adls_files(cont) # I need access to the entire container to run this
```

Problems are that with "list_storage_containers", one can list the containers of an ADLS, and with "storage_container" one can list the directories in a container.

I actually want to list the contents of a DIRECTORY within the container in question, and to also read a csv that is that directory as a DataFrame (perhaps using "dask" library)

Here is the documentation of AzureStor in case: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureStor/vignettes/generics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read list of contents from specific directory with Azure AD authentication using below code:

```
library(AzureStor)

token <- AzureRMR::get_azure_token("https://storage.azure.com",
                                   tenant="<tenantId>", app="<clientId>", password="<clientSecret>")
ad_endp_tok <- storage_endpoint("https://<ADLSName>.dfs.core.windows.net", token=token)

cont <- storage_container(ad_endp_tok, "<containerName>")
list_storage_files(cont,"<directory>")
```

[image]

You can read csv file from specified directory using below code:

```
storage_download(cont, "inputs/input.csv", "in.csv")
df = read.csv("in.csv")
```

[image]